# How to extract URLs from within a string containing markup?

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = '[url=http://domain.com]My Webpage[/url][img]http://domain.com/image1.jpg[/img][center][img]http://domain.com/image2.gif[/img][/center][center][thumb]http://domain.com/image3.png[/thumb][/center]';
preg_match_all('/.*?\[img|thumb\](http.+?)\[\/.*+/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Trying to get array of images (image1.jpg, image2.gif, image3.png). Image may be between `[img][\img]` and `[thumb][\thumb]`. And i also need to check a full line `[center][thumb]http://domain.com/image3.png[/thumb][/center]` to change it with other image. Can someone help on it?

Comment: You should not try to use regular expressions for parsing. Use a loop iterating from one `strpos()` result to the next. Will be faster and work solidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following pattern extracts it all.

```
@\[(img|thumb)\](.+?)\[/\\1@
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/bLkj3X)